# JQuery UI sortable - possible to cancel specific elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

So I have two lists, connected in one-direction so that items from one can go to the other, but nothing can move into the origin list. What kind of click function do i need so that I can move items back from where they came?

```
  $(function() {
    $( ".current-campaign , .past-campaigns, .new-campaign" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".new-campaign",
      handle: ".panel-heading",
      cancel: ".portlet-toggle",
      placeholder: "panel-placeholder",
      containment: "document",
      delay: 150,
      opacity: .75,
      revert: 50,
      start: function(e, ui){
        ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
      }
    });
```

#### New Campaign

```
<ul class="new-campaign">
</ul>
```

#### Past Campaigns

```
<ul class="past-campaigns">

  <li>
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"> Message

          <a class="pull-right cancel" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></h3> 
        <span>Voiced by: Joe</span>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Message Copy
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

I've tried doing something like this, but it doesn't work (albeit i'm no pro at javascript)

```
$( ".cancel ").click(function() {
  $( this ).sortable( "cancel" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to detach all of the elements on your second list and append the back to the first list. If order is important to you, then you need to create some ordering logic using something like a data-attribute that represents the order the elements on the first list were originally in.

For example:

```
<li data-order="1">...</li>
<li data-order="2">...</li>
<li data-order="3">...</li>
...
```

Use jQuery's detach function to remove an element from the DOM, but maintain a reference to it in memory so that you may insert it somewhere else.
Example:

```
var items = $('li').detach()
$('#someDivId').append(items)
```

Wrap that in a click function and you should be good to go. The jQuery documentation for the methods mentioned above can be found at:

- [Detach](https://api.jquery.com/detach/)
- [Append](https://api.jquery.com/append/)